# Keep Column Order when renaming Attribute

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-table

Im renaming an attribute by

```
layer.startEditing()
    layer.renameAttribute(layer.fieldNameIndex("Old Name"), "New name")
layer.commitChanges()
```

Which works fine. But in the attribute table, the renamed column is then displayed to the very right, after all other columns.

How do I keep it at its position?

Its just the display order and not re-ordered in the file behind, but still unhandy.

I've seen this on other changes to Attributes, too. However, the only one I can reproduce is this one.

Comment: I noticed this before, one workaround I used was to remove and re-add the layer. The table should be updated correctly.